# gwt-popup in wrong position for latest chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

With the latest version of chrome: Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit), as well as Chromium: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)
I have an issue where when creating a gwt-SuggestBoxPopup, the position coordinates being passed are incorrect.

I've tested this against all the other browsers, IE, Firefox and Safari, they all work there, even the older version of chrome (Version 60.0.3112.78) worked fine. I've also tested this on a Linux, Windows and Mac machines Nothing has changed on my end so I know for a fact something has changed on Chrome's end with the new update.

The only thing now is trying to figure out of this is a bug or a Chrome change, and if it is a chrome change, where that is documented.

Comment: May be it is related to this known bug: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9542

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in GWT version 2.8.2. Its release notes state that "Chrome 61 removed functionality that had been used for reading the absolute top/left values. The internal implementation has been updated to reflect modern standards.".